# how do i debug pindown python script?

Tags: python

I'm try to work this python script aangfanboy/pindown in github

but I got this bug

```
Opening browser...:   0%|                                                                       | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49614/devtools/browser/9501c6f7-21b0-4297-96fb-e44c4fcfa4cb
Going to link...:   8%|█████▍                                                           | 1/12 [00:05<01:01,  5.63s/it][0122/062528.296:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=art (0)
Starting download...:  42%|█████████████████████████▍                                   | 5/12 [00:10<00:26,  3.82s/it][0122/062531.262:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", source: https://s.pinimg.com/webapp/js/pjs-entryChunk-www-unauth-93845af8c143b49d2f47.mjs (1)
Starting download...:  42%|█████████████████████████▍                                   | 5/12 [00:10<00:15,  2.18s/it]
```

I can't find any image about art

```
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x02F12C88>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\windows user name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 945, in __del__
        self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
      File "C:\Users\windows user name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1344, in _internal_poll
        if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

can you help me here?

You can get full codes from https://github.com/aangfanboy/pindown

Comment: You didn't post where this error gets raised. We only see that it's inside Popen, but where's this Popen or subprocess?

Comment: Also, you should post a _minimal_ reproducible example. We can't just go through whole code on all questions.